# Jetpack Compose: cached ComposeView can not show in Fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use viewPager2 in my project the parent is HomeFragment and one of child Fragment is Fragmentone . I cached the root View of HomeFragment so next time I goto HomeFragment I can reuse it . ComposeView is add to Fragmentone. it can not show when I goto HomeFragment again.

class HomeFragment : BaseTrackFragment() {

```
lateinit var mTabs: TabLayout
private lateinit var mFragmentPager: ViewPager2
private var pageAdapter:HomePageAdapter? = null
val mFragmentList = SparseArray<Fragment>()
private var mView: View? = null
override fun initShareTrackParams(shareTrackParamsCtx: ShareTrackParamsCtx) {
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    if (mView!=null){
        (mView?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(mView)
        return mView as View
    }
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    mView = root

    mTabs = root.findViewById(R.id.tab_header)
    mFragmentPager = root.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager)

    try {
        setupViewPager()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }

    return root
}

private fun setupViewPager() {

    pageAdapter = HomePageAdapter(mFragmentList,this)
    mFragmentPager?.adapter = pageAdapter
    mFragmentPager.isSaveEnabled = false

    mTabs.layoutParams = mTabs.layoutParams.apply {
        width = 2 * 120
    }

    TabLayoutMediator(mTabs, mFragmentPager) { t, position ->
        t.text = if (position==0) "音乐" else "K歌"
    }.attach()

    mTabs.disableTooltips()
}
private fun TabLayout.disableTooltips() {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val c = getChildAt(i)
        if (c is ViewGroup) {
            for (j in 0 until c.childCount) {
                val cc = c.getChildAt(j)
                if (cc is TabLayout.TabView) {
                    // Avoid calling tooltip for L and M devices because long pressing twuice may freeze devices.
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(cc, null)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
 class Fragmentone : BaseTrackFragment(){
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    override fun initShareTrackParams(shareTrackParamsCtx: ShareTrackParamsCtx) {
    }

    var listView:ListView?=null
    var composeView:ComposeView?=null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmentone, container, false).apply {
            listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_view)
            composeView = findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).apply {
                setContent {
                    Text(text = "我是测试的。。。。。")
                }
            }

            listView?.adapter = MyAdapter(this.context)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment Fragmentone.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Fragmentone().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.Fragmentone">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? "it can now show" is too vague. Either way your "cache" do not have much to do with anything since it's not even used

Comment: mView is the root View of HomeFragment next time I goto HomeFragment if mView is not null I will reuse it as rootView so the step of  setupViewPager() will not do again . ComposeView is in Fragmentone . when I debugging I found bock in setContent{} not run at that time.